# Banner Not Appearing In FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

At one point it was working, but after many changes I hadn't realize it stopped.
The site works completely fine in Chrome, and almost entire in IE. Firefox just doesn't show the banner at all and playing with the CSS has not worked.

I'm not sure if its my divs or perhaps something Firefox specific. Would someone be willing to help?

I'm sorry if the the CSS is sloppy to read.

```
    <!-- Primary Page Layout
================================================== -->
<script async="" src="/scripts/ga.js"></script><script src="scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>

<!-- Delete everything in this .container and get started on your own site! -->
<div id="sizefix" class="wrapper">

<header id="mast" class="short">
<h1><a href="#"></a></h1>

<nav id="nav-logo" class="sample">   
<img src="stylesheets\images\logo.png"></img><img src="stylesheets\images\name.png"></img>
</nav>
<nav id="primary-nav">
<ul class="nav-tabs">
<li>
<a href="#aboutme" class="about">About me</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#resume" class="resume">Resume</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#portfolio" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
    header#mast{margin:0 0 0 -2000px;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;left:50%;z-index:100;}
    header#mast.tall{height:100px;}
    header#mast.short{height:100px;}


    header#mast h1{margin:0 62px 0 10px;width:600px;height:208px;}
    header#mast h1 a{width:168px;height:150px;display:block;text indent:-9999px;background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;}
    header#mast.short h1{margin:0px auto;width:200%;height:10px;}
    header#mast.short h1 a{width:250%;height:170px;background:url(images/header.png);}


    #nav-logo{margin:5px 0 0 1520px;height:24px;width: 100%;}
    #primary-nav{margin-top:30px;margin-right:-13px;height:20px;width:300%;float:left;background:url(images/) no-repeat; }
    #primary-nav ul{margin:25px 0 0 1680px;}
    #primary-nav li{margin:0 7px;}
    #primary-nav a{padding:10px;display:block;font:23px/1 "SteelfishRegular","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;}
    #primary-nav a.about{color:#05d205;text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) 0 1px 0;}
    #primary-nav a.portfolio{color:#df0a0a;text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) 0 1px 0;}
    #primary-nav a.resume{color:#1E8FF8;text-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 0;}
    #primary-nav a.contact{color:#c105c1;text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) 0 1px 0;}
    #primary-nav a:hover{padding:10px;color:#063959;display:block;font:23px/1 "SteelfishRegular","HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;}
    header#mast p.about{margin:36px 0 0 0;width:205px;height:90px;float:right;background:url(/images/bg_primary-nav.png) top right no-repeat;}
    header#mast p.about a{margin:24px 20px 0 12px;padding:10px;display:block;font:20px/1 "CoffeeService",Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:#ffffff 0 1px 0;}
```

Comment: change `<img src="stylesheets\images\logo.png"><img src="stylesheets\images\name.png">` to `<img src="stylesheets/images/logo.png"><img src="stylesheets/images/name.png">` will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your html code here

```
<nav class="sample" id="nav-logo">   
    <img src="stylesheets\images\logo.png"><img src="stylesheets\images\name.png">
</nav>
```

`src` should be given like `stylesheets/images/logo.png` and not `stylesheets\images\logo.png` which causes the mentioned issue.

also just to mention, your background for

```
header#mast h1 a{width:168px;height:150px;display:block;text indent:-9999px;background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;}
```

is overriden by the background of the following

```
header#mast.short h1 a{width:250%;height:170px;background:url(images/header.png);}
```

inspect your page with [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Looking in firebug, its telling me "failed to load the given URL" for both the logos not in the CSS.
The banner works fine if I open the HTML file from my hard drive and not the domain/web. Odd.

Comment: just see my updated answer.. go to html and correct the src of images. use `/` instead of \ in src..